# App extension keyboard key being cut off on press

Tags: ios, ios8, ios-app-extension

I have a keyboard that works fine except that the magnified view of the key (for keys on the top row) is cut off. It's basically a similar effect to the regular ios keyboard:[image]

I'm looking to achieve something like that in the picture. How can I prevent my views from being limited to the keyboard container? The key is a button which has it's image changed upon press down.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in iOS 8.

The [Custom Keyboard Extension docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html) state:

> Finally, it is not possible to display key artwork above the top edge of a custom keyboard’s primary view, as the system keyboard does on iPhone when you tap and hold a key in the top row.

Comment: I have no idea how I missed that. Thank you very much!